# How to start a timer from zero in iOS

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I have a button on which i have placed a UITapGestureRecognizer. When i tap on that button, i call a method that starts the time. 
My question is, i am able to get the timer string on a label. But the timer starts from current date-time, and i want to start the timer always from zero(like a countdown timer). Here below is my code for timer.

```
-(IBAction)micPressed{
if (gestureRecognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    gestureRecognizer.view.alpha=0.2f;

    [label setHidden:NO];

    if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
}
else{
    [label setHidden:YES];

    gestureRecognizer.view.alpha=10.2f;
    if ([_timer isValid]) {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }
    _timer = nil;
}

}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

 NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss:SSS"];

NSString *dateInStringFormated=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateInStringFormated);
[label setText:dateInStringFormated];
}
```

Please can anyone suggest me the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer. It will start with zero as you required!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like,

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss:SSS"];

NSString *dateInStringFormated=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[dateformatter dateFromString:@"00:00:000"]];
NSLog(@"test : %@",dateInStringFormated);
```

I have just chage `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]` with `[dateformatter dateFromString:@"00:00:000"]`.

It will start with zero always.

**Update :**

I think you want something like timer that update minutes,seconds and milliseconds as i understand your question now. You can achieve it something like,

Schedule timer like,

```
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Now your `updateTimer` should be like,

```
 -(void)updateTimer{

 static double counter = 0;

 static int counter2 = 0;


int seconds = (int)counter % 60;
int minutes = ((int)counter / 60) % 60;


NSLog(@"%02d:%02d:%03d",minutes,seconds,counter2); // This should be your labels text that updating continuously




counter = counter + 0.01;
counter2++;

if (counter2 == 100) {
    counter2 = 0;
}
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: the timer does starts from zero, but it remains the same throughout(00:00:000). please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are starting your timer from current time itself. To make a like countdown timer. You need to do the following:

1. Take an `int` named `Counter` and intialize it from `0`
2. Fire your `NSTimer` and at that time increase the counter
3. Display the counter value in the `UILabel` text.
4. Once your `NSTimer` stops, again make it to `0`.

That's it! This is how you can achieve the desired result.

> Code:

```
int counter = 0;

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    counter++;
}
```

Once `NSTimer` is invalidate again make it to `counter = 0`

Comment: i tried it, but the counter just increments by one. What i want is when i tap and hold the press, i want the timer to be running(incrementing), till i release the button.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have set the repeats to NO. i changed it, and the timer is incrementing. But i want the timer in this format-( mm:ss:SSS ), can you help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the time when you have started the timer:

```
_startDate = [NSDate date];
_Timer = ...
```

Then use the time interval since the start date in your `_timerFired` method:

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateInStringFormatted = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate]];
```